# Check queue return status

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working with Laravel 4.2 queue function. Right now I have a function will do the process for data then return some result back to function. My problem is, how could I check the status that returned from the queue?

Code

Controller function

```
public function destroy($id, $message = '')
    {
        //Calling queue
        Queue::push('InvoiceQueue@delete_invoice', [
            'id' => $id,
            'Class' => $this->Class,

        ]);
        //continue the function after returned from the queue 

        //Do validation based on queue returned status
        $instance = $this->Class;
        $record = $instance::findOrFail($id);

        //Restore the DB if queue returned an error
        if ($record->restore()) {

        }

        //Delete the DB if queue process working fine
        else {

        return parent::destroy($id, trans("$this->class.invoice"));
     }
    }
```

Queue function

```
public function delete_invoice($job, $data)
    {
        try {
            return DB::transaction(function ()use ($job,$data) {

            //Doing some process here, go to Catch if an error

            });
        } catch (TransactionException $e) {

            return Response::json(['errors' => array_flatten($e->getErrors())], 400);
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure how to do the validation in the controller function based on queue returned result. The code above always execute the `restore()` and never go to else statement.

Comment: The whole point of delegating to the queue is to execute that code outside of your current context, so your code doesn't have to wait for the queue job to finish. That means that the job can't return any results. If you're depending on the result of a particular piece of code in order for your controller action to continue, then your should just call that method/function directly without pushing it to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of queue is not right here.

queues just can run tasks and you can store their results to whenever you want ( like DB or LogFiles , Redis ... )

The right usage of queue is for the codes that

> **you don't want to run them through your main codes(Current), because you don't have direct access to the queue result(consider that maybe your queue stop at the time(for some bug fix implementation) or your jobs will only run at midnight , it depends on your business logic)**

Or

> **you are using an external services (for example : sending emails ,
> sending notifies ...) and the results is not important for your
> current codes**

Or

> **You want to answer to an external request before the main process**

And queues are here to ensure that :

> **they are going to do your requested process (for example sending an email) if it takes a whole day retrying, to
> do it ( sending that email )**

*or you can simply mark them as failed job (due to getting failed bcs of network or codes issues after specific numbers of retry) to store them somewhere and after fixing bugs, retry them*  Any way,they are not loosing any data unless they get true from the results